# Detecting CSS capabilities with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, browser

Is it possible to detect CSS support by using Javascript?

For example, is it possible to detect if the browser supports attribute selectors like this?

```
input[type='text'] { }
```

Comment: How would this be useful? You have to run JavaScript to check, so you might as well just run JavaScript to [add support for it](http://selectivizr.com/).

Comment: @thirtydot, yeah I know what you're saying, but I guess that the less work the browser has to do in Javascript, the better. If the CSS engine can handle it, why waste precious cycles? ;)

Comment: Because the CSS engine (in IE6-8) *can't* handle it. Selectivizr immediately quits if the browser is not IE6-8 (the only common browsers that don't support this stuff). Otherwise, it runs and adds support for a bunch of lovely selectors.

Answer (score 5):

Modernizr is designed to detect browser features and may well be able to help in this instance.
http://www.modernizr.com/

Comment: Only really detects new stuff... `[attr]` selectors are everywhere (except IE6)

Comment: Modernizr is for HTML4-->5 transitional coding, not a generic toolkit for checking legacy browser capabilities. Bad (and imo, incorrect) use for this library. Use it to make sure that you can work with a "canvas" and other new elements regardless of HTML5 support, not to verify that legacy capabilities still exist in a browser.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit speculative as I haven't tested it out, but I believe it would be possible via JS to add a `style` element followed by an element that it has an effect on, and then test the values:

Speculative untested code, may or may not work (jQuery used for brevity):

```
$('<style type="text/css" id="foo">input[type="text"]{ width: 10px; }</style>').appendTo('head');
$('<input type="text" id="bar">').appendTo('body');
if ($('#bar').width() == 10)
{
  //attr selector supported
}
$('#foo, #bar').remove();
```

Comment: +1 for the approach, as its probably the only way you will be able to detect it.

Comment: Agree with @gnarf on this one - short of a try catch around querySelector or some other hack...

Answer (score 2):

```
document.querySelectorAll("input[type='text']")
```

But that fails for older browsers, naturally.

Other than that, you could just use the `style` property to check if a certain CSS property has been applied or not.

```
input[type='text'] {
  background-repeat: no-repeat; /* or any other irrelevant, non-default value */
}
```

and

```
if (myInputElem.style.backgroundRepeat == "no-repeat") {
  // selector is supported
}
```

Comment: Anything that supports qSA supports `[attr]` selectors

Comment: @gnarf: That's probably true. Checking for the existence of that function might be a hint as well, even though that's not exactly what has been asked for.